# Is there a natural language in which grammatical number is used to denote "all" of something (as distinct from simply "many" of something?)

Tags: grammatical-number

I am working on a constructed language, and this is a feature I have been considering. My conlang has singular, dual, and plural numbers that function as one would expect. This "omnic" number would denote "all" or "every" of a noun. I'm not entirely sure how to classify, let alone gloss, something like that, and my research to find a natural language to draw from has been without fruit. I'd greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Not a natural language (and you may be familiar with this already), but High Valyrian from _Game of Thrones_, created by David J. Peterson has essentially that. It has singular, dual, paucal (a few or some, seen individually) and collective (a great many or all, seen collectively) numbers for nouns.

Comment: Correction: Valyrian has singular, _plural_, paucal and collective – no dual.

Comment: An older conlang: Quenya has two plurals, one of which is some kind of collective; I have not seen it explained clearly enough for me.